# luasocket + copas error - attempt to yield across C-call boundary

Tags: lua, luasocket, copas

I'm new to Lua and trying to implement TCP server and client in Openwrt using [luasocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) and [copas](http://keplerproject.github.io/copas/). The goal is to make 3 program communicate with each other via socket in asynchronous networking.

Below is the script

```
local copas = require("copas")
local socket = require("socket")

local host = "localhost"
local port = 20000

local hostcl1 = "localhost"
local portcl1 = 20001

local hostcl2 = "localhost"
local portcl2 = 20002

local function echoHandler(skt)
    skt = copas.wrap(skt)
    while true do
        local data = skt:receive()
        print("data received:", data, "from:", skt:getsockname())
        if not data or data == nil then
            break
        end
    end
end

local function sendToNeighbor(host, port, data)
    skt = socket.connect(host, port)
    if (skt ~= nil) then
        skt = copas.wrap(skt)
        print("client connected to " ..host.. ":" ..port.. "...")
        copas.send(skt, data.."\n")
        print("data sent")
        skt:close()
        print("Closed!")
    else
        print("client failed to send to " ..host.. ":" ..port.. "...")
    end
end

local server = socket.bind(host, port)

copas.addserver(server, echoHandler, 0)

SendInterval = 10
SecBefore = os.date('%S')
SecSend = (SecBefore + SendInterval)%60

while true do
    copas.step(0)
    local Sec = os.date('%S')
    if ( tonumber(Sec) == SecSend ) then
        dataToClient1 = "Test1"
        dataToClient2 = "Test2"
        sendToNeighbor(hostcl1, portcl1, dataToClient1)
        sendToNeighbor(hostcl2, portcl2, dataToClient2)
        SecBefore = Sec
        SecSend = (SecBefore + SendInterval)%60
    end
end
```

On script above, I use 3 similar program in host = "localhost" and 3 different port (20000, 20001, and 20002). I want each program listen to each other and send each other data every 10 seconds. The problem is every time the program send data with copas.send function, this error occurs.

```
luajit: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/copas.lua:285: attempt to yield across C-call boundary
```

I have try using lua 5.1, lua 5.1 + CoCo, and LuaJIT and this error always occur. 
Any idea to solve this? thanks